# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a linear map...

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a linear map $T(x,y,z) = (z,x,y)$ and I got my characteristic polynomial to be $1-\lambda^3$ which means there is one real eigenvalue $\lambda=1$.

Is this correct?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: No love for $\exp(i2\pi/3)$ and $\exp(i4\pi/3)$?

Comment: @DavidKraemer: Not Real eigens.

Comment: Yea not worried about them!!!

Comment: Since there is only 1 real eigenvalue does that mean T is diagonalizable???

Comment: @squenshl: It depends on whether you have 3 L.I eigenvectors, i.e., on Geometric multiplicity.

Comment: Then it is then as $(1,1,1)$ is the eigenvector associated with $\lambda=1$. Not worried about the complex ones!!!

Comment: No, it is not, for an nxn matrix you need n L.I Eigenvectors to diagonalize.

Comment: Sorry that’s what I meant I missed “not” between “is” and “then” in my previous comment.

Comment: To diagonalize a matrix over the reals you need a basis that consists entirely of real eigenvectors. It’s going to be hard to find three linearly-independent _real_ eigenvectors when the only real eigenvectors are multiples of $(1,1,1)^T$.